# Text file read lost formatting vs slowdown

Tags: file, text, stream, formatting

I've been trying to work this out for a while.

Reading a text file.

Using this code the formatting gets replaced with the getline...but the time to load the file is simply too long...

```
    std::string line = "";
    std::string file = "";
    std::ifstream filepath(path);

    if (filepath.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline (filepath,line) )
        {                   
        file = file + line  + "\r\n";
        }

        filepath.close();
    }
```

Using this code the time to load the file is around 10X faster, but the formatting is lost:

```
        std::ifstream in(path);
        std::stringstream stream;

        stream << in.rdbuf();

        std::string file(stream.str());
```

Is it possible to get the speed of the second method with the formatting of the first...?  Or better yet faster speeds and no change in formatting?

I had considered trying not to keep loading the same string in the first example at each getline in the loop but early attempts didn't seem to help.

Comment: as you are using C++ builder you can use `FileOpen/Seek/FileRead/FileWrite/FileClose`  you can load the entire text  file into memory without any changes ... fstreams are slow and are also processing control codes (that is why the content is changed). If you want quick access to text files you can also use `Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile("file.txt")` where Memo1 is VCL TMemo  object (you need to add it onto your form). It does not need to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after checking again, not sure what this is called but this string optimization took care of the delay and the formatting... whew!

If anyone knows how to make it even faster I'd love to learn how...

```
    std::string line = "";
    std::string file = "";
    std::string tmp_str = "";
    std::ifstream filepath(path);
    unsigned int c = 0;

    if (filepath.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline (filepath,line) )
        {
            tmp_str = tmp_str + line + "\r\n";
            c++;
            if (c > 100)
            {
                file = file + tmp_str;
                tmp_str = "";
                c = 0;
            }
        }

        if (c != 0) 
        {
            file = file + tmp_str;
        }

        filepath.close();
```